# Track Customer Product changes within a month

Tags: sql, plsql

I need to count how many transfers were done by customers within the same month for the below listed products(voice,data,sms)

Here is some sample data

```
Month        Customer No Product

01/Dec/2012  123         Voice
03/Dec/2012  123         Data
05/Dec/2012  345         Voice
09/Dec/2012  333         Voice
02/Dec/2012  333         data
```

Here is the expected output

```
Month   From_Product To_Product Customer_Total

Dec2012 Voice        Data       1
Dec2012 Data         Voice      1
```

Hope this makes sense.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this using `lead()` and aggregation:

```
select to_char(month, 'YYYY-MM') as mon, product as from_product, to_product,
       count(*) as customer_total
from (select sd.*,
             lead(product) over (partition by customer, to_char(month, 'YYYY-MM') order by month) as to_product
      from sampledata sd
     ) sd
where to_product is not null
group by to_char(month, 'YYYY-MM');
```